# TableLayout refuses to match_parent

Tags: android, xml, layout, tablelayout

I have an xml layout which serves as an item in a ListView. The thing is: when it's added there, the item's width isn't stretched to `match_parent`, it wraps content instead. It is used in a ListView, so its width needs to be `match_parent`. I've been reading about it all over stackoverflow, trying every solution availible, but I have had zero result: `layout_weight` set to 1 does nothing to my layout, stretching columns has given me the best result in terms of width, but in terms of layout itself it failed miserably.

Is there anything that can be done here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/trackCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:duplicateParentState="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trackNumberText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="00."
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trackTitleText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trackArtistText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Artist" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the listview? And the above xml you are using as a child of listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the mentioned solutions have helped me, so trying to solve this for 3 days I found a solution myself. Unfortunately, the solution is programmatical, the following code is to be added to your custom adapter:

```
trackCheckBox.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
trackNumberText.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - trackCheckBox.getMeasuredWidth() - trackNumberText.getMeasuredWidth();

trackArtistText.setWidth(width);
trackTitleText.setWidth(width);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add  [`android:stretchColumns="*"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns) property in your `TableLayout`

## android:stretchColumns

> The zero-based index of the columns to stretch. The column indices
>   must be separated by a comma: 1, 2, 5. Illegal and duplicate indices
>   are ignored. You can stretch all columns by using the value "*"
>   instead. Note that a column can be marked stretchable and shrinkable
>   at the same time.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

.....

</TableLayout>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: oh ok... I didn't know you could set it xml ... * to the rescue

Comment: Sorry, in the post I said I have already tried this. It didn't lead to the desired layout, though it did the trick of setting layout width to match_parent. You should see for yourself what I'm trying to achieve by copying this code into your android studio and then adding the stretch columns parameter to the code to see what actually happens

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);`. Unfortunately you cannot set that in xml, perhaps place it in your adapter.